# Identify and name a timestamp for specific data entry points

Tags: postgresql

I have a situation where I'm trying to look at changes in data based on timestamp of user entry (or 'created on').

The data highlights planning for delivery of goods, users have the ability to 're-plan' their dates of entry.

What I need to do is look at the timestamp for each 're-planning' date and be able to tell if the date of planning was changed within 7 days of delivery. For example

Data line XXY was planned for delivery on the 29th of August, 2017...but was changed, ON the 27th, to the 30th....this is a flag...

Like wise XXZ was planned for the 30th but changed to September 15th on the 29th...also a flag. Both were changed within 7 days of their previous 'delivery' date. Does this make sense and is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Please add some sample data and your expected output. This really helps to fully understand your problem.

Comment: Please read https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql for an introduction on how to ask a good question regarding SQL. Then **[EDIT]** your question and add the missing information as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), do **NOT** post code in comments.